# Does Apple provide servers for app developers?

Tags: ios, server, iphone-developer-program

I have read that Apple does provide their own servers for app developers - but I can't seem to find it anymore.

So does anyone know, if Apple provides a servers and its maintenance for like a multiplayer app or does the developer have to construct his own server?

Comment: Why would you think that Apple would provide the web hosting for your game? I don't think you understood whatever you read correctly.

Comment: Check out Game Center: https://developer.apple.com/game-center/